# Access tokens - How do I get them?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, fetch, access-token

I have a simple question: How can I get a users access token??

I only need the basic information, so when a user clicks on "allow" on my page, I want to be able to get That users picture/username etc.

To do this i need to fetch the access token of that user.

Comment: Can you specify which technology or framework are you using? php, asp or pure javascript?

Comment: I'm using php and javascript, but php would certainly be best!

Comment: Then the access token is available using $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();  Are you using the PHP Facebook SDK ?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what "PHP Faccebook SDK" is, if i'm being perfectly honest. :p Do I have to download this or?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP the access Token is available to your application after a successfull user login. That means that you should write the code to do that. Personally I have a simple PHP page (fblogin.php) that I open in a new window, here's the code (it uses facebook sdk, be sure to download it, also remember to create an application in facebook in case you dont have one)

```
require_once ('facebook/src/facebook.php');

// handel cancel
if (isset($_REQUEST['error_reason'])) {
     echo("<script>self.close();</script>");
     exit;
}

// ger request params
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
$my_url = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/fblogin.php';
$api_key = 'YOURAPIKEY';
$secret = 'YOURSECRETCODE';

// build login url
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday',
    'display' => 'popup',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.yourdomain.com/fblogin.php'
    ));

// if no facebook code is given, write login back againg to the window
if(empty($code)) {

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
    exit;

} else {

        //set token for facebook object from graph
        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
           . "client_id=" . $api_key . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
           . "&client_secret=" . $secret . "&code=" . $code;

        $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);

        $facebook->setAccessToken($params['access_token']);
        $fbme = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET');



        if ($fbme) {
            // YOU got the user, id, token, etc. 
                        // do anything you want here,
        } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) I will try this! I'm a beginner when it comes to php/websiting, and this problem has been killing me!

Comment: One question; this php-script that you wrote.. Should I put it in a "fblogin.php" file? Or in the index file?

Comment: well this is an example PHP file, what it does is display the facebook login window, so you should open it in a new window, index is not a good idea. If you're a beginner you should go to http://developers.facebook.com and start learning how it works, download the PHP SDK , learn it and use it. Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

To get an access token, you must have an account at Facebook. If you have already the account, you should go to developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api. On this page, you have examples of using a Graph API then you had a generated access token. And than you have examples with results in JSON. There is  graph.facebook.com/your_id_number <- the basic, public information about your in web or graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token="here is an 116 length combination of numbers and letters". The access token is hidden between examples ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already been reading everything about api and graph! And I could never really get an answer to my problem! 
No worries :P your English is just fine.. I myself is not a native speaker, so I don't care about grammar! :D

Comment: I've the same problem as you but I need an access token for Bash. I make a script which uses rusty or curl and I need a token to access when i login via curl ... than I send a received information by stream to jsawk to processing it ...

Comment: Editing a four years old 0-voted answer for grammarz takes some serious dedication, congrats!

Comment: I see progress between then and now. It is worth a lot for me.